# Integrating web3 in cloud functions module

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, ethereum, truffle, web3js

I'm trying to integrate web3 (using truffle) in a cloud functions module and I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
```

Here is part of the implementation:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const db = admin.database();

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, infura link);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

As Far as I understand, the error indicates that *truffle* library is unable to establish a connection to the ethereum network. I wonder if this has something to do with deploying this code to firebase.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey are you doing like this, deploying a smart contract code by using  Cloud Functions using web3Jdeploy code isn't it?

Comment: Hi @DivyaGalla, it seems there was an error in the cloud functions, thanks anyway!

Comment: How are you doing this, I am asking because I too want to implement like you.

Comment: Hey did you get this issue fixed? If so how? Looking into the same thing.

Comment: yes, apparently this was caused due to a bug in our code.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue and my problem was that my dev project was on the free "Spark" tier for Firebase. Outgoing network requests in Cloud Functions requires that you are on a paid plan, so I upgraded to the "Blaze" tier which is pay as you go and my web3 cloud functions started working immediately.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Hey, @Dan can you upload your cloud functions which contain the web3js equivalent code of a smart contract if possible.

Comment: @DivyaGalla Can't upload my code in particular but web3 with cloud functions is very straight forward if you have used web3 inside NodeJS. I put all my code inside a database event function which can be found here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events. You can look at an example of the web3 code here https://github.com/ThatOtherZach/Web3-by-Example/blob/master/scripts/contract-function.js the Web3 HttpProvider I use is https://mainnet.infura.io/

Answer (score 0):

Yes same here, upgrading to paid plan establishes a connection to my Infura node